# cell value change not getting captured in vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to capture when value changes in the cell `A2`

I tried the below code but it is not working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H5")) Is Nothing Then Macro
End Sub
```

I have a breakpoint inside the macro but its not coming till there
I also tried the below, but no luck

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox (Target.Column)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Worksheet_Change` takes a single parameter `Target` of type `Range`.  To check if you have changed the range you are interested in you can compare the target to that range, in your case:

```
If Target = Range("A2") Then
    'Do something
End If
```

This lets you compare a `Range` object with another `Range` object with minimal fuss.

And also put it in the correct sheet.... :P

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason

I placed the macro in wrong place i.e in a different module

For the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` to work, 
we need to place it in the sheet which needs that detection
I followed the below steps

1. We need to go to Excel VBA editor by pressing ALT + F11
2. Double click on sheet which contains our target cell e.g. Sheet1
3. Add the below code to the sheet